# Need for IPTables expert, possibly with knowledge of u32 module

Tags: iptables, dns

A customer is sending queries against DNS root-servers on my recursive DNS server. I need to block it with iptables. I tried 3 examples but it is not working.

```
0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       1.111.111.111        0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 STRING match  "a.root-servers.net" ALGO name kmp TO 65535 /* root */
0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 u32 "0x1c&0xf8=0x0" STRING match  "a.root-servers.net" ALGO name bm FROM 40 TO 65535
0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53 STRING match  "a.root-servers.net" ALGO name bm TO 65535
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I also recommend not posting your real public IP addresses.

Comment: BIND? why not blocking it on the DNS server or implementing rate limiting? Your problem is that you are forgetting DNS is UDP *and* TCP.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for editing the IP. It is not BIND is PowerDNS and at first glance seems does not have rate limit as default function. It support LUA scripting but I don't know it.
The queries against root server are all in UDP
Thanks

Comment: What is the exact IPtable command you are using? It should be `iptables -I INPUT -s 1.111.11.111 -j DROP`

Comment: Unfortunately that is NAT IP with 90 customers behind it. I cannot block the IP. I need to block only DNS queries for root server a

Comment: I know I could fight that in BIND, I do not know PowerDNS that well. Having people coming from NATs to your service is *a very bad idea*. I doubt wether blocking it in iptables alone will work 100% of the time for several reasons, including DNS resiliency. You can try blocking on the source AND payload, however that is a though one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649156/how-to-use-bpf-filter-to-filter-packet-payload